# How to get consistent timestamps from Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, timestamp

After authenticating through Firebase, one of the timestamp fields from the user data when console logged shows up as `Fri Dec 02 2022 11:50:37 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)`. I haven't had the need to process any timestamps on my project so I just left that as is.

I tried to fetch data from my Firestore that included another timestamp field and somehow I get a different format. It shows as:

```js
ut {seconds: 1670006748, nanoseconds: 11000000}
```

Is there a way for me to ensure that any timestamps coming from Firebase are returned to my application in a consistent format? I will eventually write a utility file on my React project to handle all of my date/time needs and I just want to be ready when I get to that point.

Comment: Have you tried fetching the timestamp to try to convert it? Sample code: // to get as date 
const date = new TimeStamp(yourTimeStamp.seconds , yourTimeStamp.nanoseconds).toDate();
// to get as string 
const date = new TimeStamp(yourTimeStamp.seconds , yourTimeStamp.nanoseconds).toDate().toDateString();

Comment: I'll post it as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried fetching the timestamp to try to convert it?

Sample code:

```
// to get as date 
const date = new TimeStamp(yourTimeStamp.seconds , yourTimeStamp.nanoseconds).toDate(); 
// to get as string 
const date = new TimeStamp(yourTimeStamp.seconds , yourTimeStamp.nanoseconds).toDate().toDateString();
```